# Position sticky doesn't work with display:grid in Safari

Tags: css, safari, css-grid, mobile-safari, sticky

I have problem with STICKY position in Safari. Chrome is working well. I tried many times but no result. I need only display:grid, not block. Thanks for help;

````
```
 <div class="calendarWrap">
    <div class="calendarHeader">
        bla bla bla
    </div>
 </div>
```


<pre>
.calendarWrap {
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 3.4rem 1fr;
}

.calendarHeader {
  position: sticky;
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
  height: 35px;
  top: 0;
  border-bottom: 0.5px solid $border-color-input-light;
  overflow: hidden;
}
</pre>
````

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` from `.calendarWrap` element and it works somehow.
`overflow` is `auto` by `default`.
Remember, that the parent element must be bigger that the sticky element.

Comment: Thanks, really the problem was concerned with overflow, but in another element.

Comment: @annaswan you can click on accepted as the answer then :)